# Is there an equivalent to Java's HashSet in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I have to write something in vbscript that need to use a unique set.  I am looking for something akin to Java's HashSet, is this already in vbscript or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not identical, but VBScript has a Dictionary object which behaves like Java's Map or Hashtable.

You can use this almost like a HashSet, by just looking up the item as a key in the dictionary and finding if there is any value there. When you want to put something into the set, simply set its value to 1 or anything else.

Comment: I google vbs HashSet and found only reference to Dictionary. I was hoping for something more straightforward, but this will do the trick.